# JHipster Runs But No SSL Challenge Occurs

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, jhipster

I've recently created a PKCS keystore using LetsEncrypt and I configured my production profile for JHipster to run Tomcat on 8443 using the new keystore. I can get the application to run if I call "ciwiseaccounting.com:8443" but when the page arrives Chrome shows the "!" meaning the page is not secure. This is odd because I didn't see the SSL challenge occur. If I call "https://ciwiseaccounting.com:8443" this does not work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? IPTables is wide open for now and I can nmap the 8443 listener. Here's my server config snippet:

```
server:
   port: 8443
   server.ssl.key-store: 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/ciwiseaccounting.com/keystore.p12
   server.ssl.key-store-password: password
   server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
   server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `server` key twice in your configuration (line 1, then again on lines 3-6).  This means the properties aren't parsed into the correct variables, resulting in regular http instead of https.

Try with the below config:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        key-store: /etc/letsencrypt/live/ciwiseaccounting.com/keystore.p12
        key-store-password: password
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: tomcat
```

Comment: Jon, I need to brush up on my YAML use. Wow! Trying this now. I'll up-vote after I test. Thank you Jon.